# How to compare sublist of list with sublist of other list that are in same list of lists

Tags: python, list, comparison, sublist

I have **a list of lists with each list having sublists** for example something like the following:

```
mylist = [[['AB','CD'],['GH','EF'],['IJ','KL'],['']],[['CD','AB'],['EF','GH'],['KL','IJ'],['']],[['EF','GH'],['CD','AB'],['IJ','KL'],['']],...]
```

the number of lists are 1500 and each list of them has 16 sublists(the above is just an example). What I want to do is **compare the sublist of the one list with the sublist of the other list**, for all lists. To be more precise, I want to **compare ['AB','CD'] with ['CD','AB'] and ['EF','GH'] and the first sublist of the rest of the lists**. Same follows for the second sublist. I want to check if they have the same items, the order does not matter. So the ['AB','CD'] with ['CD','AB'] would be same. But then I need also to find which sublists contain the  ['EF','GH'] and do some calculations when all same sublists are together. 
All in all, I want to check the 1st sublist of one list with the rest of the first sublists of each list and then do the same for each sublist(2nd,3rd,4th,..,15th). 
I thought of doing something like this

```
for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
        for j in range(i,len(mylist)):
            if mylist[i][j]==mylist[i + 1][j]:
```

but it doesn't seem to work when I do so. It gives me:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I do not know if my approach is right. I tried to search and understand but I could not find something relevant.

**all sublists are of same length.**

Answer (score 0):

You are tryng to acessa index out of the list range, when i is on the last position of the list. You do not need to go to the last position, it' enougth  go to  penultimate position and compare it with the last, like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1):
    for j in range(i,len(mylist[i])):
        if mylist[i][j]==mylist[i+1][j]:
            print('Found')
```

Comment: i put a print("same") statement inside the if statement in order to see if it works and it first gives me the same error as before and then prints the word same for 10 or more times and ends..

Comment: @piggy, I've  changed the code. Forgot about the i index on the second for.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked !

Comment: I am trying to understand now how it works because as I see it only gives me results that are same only if the order in the sublist is same, while I want to return they are same even if the order is not same. And as I see it does not work. I am working on it still that's why I did not accept it yet